# c - Problems with pointers and allocation

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I have to dynamically allocate a pointer inside a while.

```
char * allocationg_memory(char [] path p) {
    char message[4000];
    char c;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    unsigned int count;
    FILE *f;

    //open the file
    f = fopen(p, "rt");
    count = 0;

    //copy the contain of the file in message
    if (f) {
            while ((c = getc(f)) != EOF) {
                    count++;
                    message[i] = c;
                    i++;
            }

            fclose(f);
    }

    //allocating the memory 
    char *str = (char *) malloc(sizeof (char) * (count));

    if (str == NULL) {
        printf("error allocating memory for string\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //copy the message
    strncpy (str, message, count);

    return str;
}

void main {
    char * ptr;
    do {
        //my path dynamically changing
        path = path_of_file;
        ptr = allocating_memory(path);
        printf("%s", ptr);
        free(ptr);
    } while (1);
 }
```

If I set ptr = NULL it gives me segmentation fault, if I don't, if the next print is bigger than the previus, the 2nd is printed over the 1st. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: My bad, it returns the pointer to the allocated memory. In my program I use it to read from different files.

Comment: It appears from a lower comment that you did the right thing in removing extra fluff and trying to diagnose the problem yourself, but it looks like you might have removed a bit too much, and it is now no longer clear what the issue is.

Comment: yes, you are right! updated!

Comment: "If I set ptr = NULL it gives me segmentation fault"... It's possible that `str` in `allocationg_memory` method is not being malloc-ed properly in one of the calls (for some reason). You may want to print a warning to console if `count` is zero after reading in the file.

Comment: Adding "str[count] = '\0';" works, but I still can't set ptr = NULL. Maybe I'm doing something wrong and I should try reallocating! Anyway it works, so thank you guys!

Comment: shouldn't I do it after "free(ptr)"?

Answer (score 2):

For starters:

1. Your initial allocation is for 0 bytes.
2. You are trying to print what you have allocated as if it were a string.
3. Your loop never ends.

Comment: 4 he has lost a parenthesis... char *str = (char *) malloc (sizeof (char) * (c); (4 opened, 3 closed)

Comment: Well, I actually read from a file and allocate based on the dimension, so I never allocate 0 unless the file is empty. My program is much bigger and I tried to change it focusing on what gives me problem.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Hopefully it helps

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char * allocating_memory(int c) {
    char *str = malloc ( c + 1); // allow an extra for the null
    strncpy ( str, "abcdefghijklmnopqustuvwxyx", c);
    str[c] = '\0'; // make sure the string is null terminated

    return str;
}

int main () {
    char * ptr;
    int counter = 2;
    do {
        ptr = NULL;
        ptr = allocating_memory(counter);
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
        free(ptr);
        counter++;
    } while (counter < 27);
    return 0;
}
```